# RoutedEvent TextBox.LostFocus not working in my WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, eventtrigger

I am working with the WPF animations using Storyboards. What I want is to fade out all the content of the page as soon as my textbox gets focus, and to fade in everything back as soon as the focus is removed from the textbox. To do that, I have the following XAML with no code behind.

```
<Page.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.GotFocus">
     <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation
              Storyboard.TargetName="Grid1"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
              From="1" To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.2"
              AutoReverse="False" >
           </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.LostFocus">
     <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation
              Storyboard.TargetName="Grid1"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
              From="0.1" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"
              AutoReverse="False">
           </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
```

To move focus out of textbox, I have the following button:

```
<Button
        Name="SearchButton" 
        Height="30" Width="30"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Focusable="True"
        IsHitTestVisible="True"
        Style="{StaticResource SearchButton}"
        Padding="3,3,3,3"
        Margin="3,3,3,3" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

When I run the app, clicking on the textbox makes the fade out work fine. But when I click on the button, the fade in does not kick in.

Can anyone please give me some insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your triggers in the `TextBox` directly, not on the `Page` level:

```
  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.GotFocus">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
               Storyboard.TargetName="Grid1"
               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
               From="1" To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.2"
               FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
            </DoubleAnimation>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.LostFocus">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
               Storyboard.TargetName="Grid1"
               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
               From="0.1" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"
               FillBehavior="Stop">
            </DoubleAnimation>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </TextBox.Triggers>
  </TextBox>
```

Otherwise, the storyboards will be triggered for each and every `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` routed event of each `UIElement` on the `Page` because of these events' bubbling strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, works like a charm for me. :D